# Activemq connection getting time out in java using fusesource

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt

Here is my java code to connect with mqtt

```
class Publisher {

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {

        String host = env("ACTIVEMQ_HOST", "192.168.1.4");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(env("ACTIVEMQ_PORT", "61614"));
        final String destination = arg(args, 0, "/topic/event");

        int messages = 10000;
        int size = 256;

        String DATA = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String body = "";
        for( int i=0; i < size; i ++) {
            body += DATA.charAt(i%DATA.length());
        }
       Buffer msg = new AsciiBuffer(body);

        MQTT mqtt = new MQTT();
        mqtt.setHost(host, port);

        System.out.println("Before await .........");
        FutureConnection connection = mqtt.futureConnection();
        connection.connect().await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("After await .........");
        final LinkedList<Future<Void>> queue = new LinkedList<Future<Void>>();
        UTF8Buffer topic = new UTF8Buffer(destination);
        for( int i=1; i <= messages; i ++) {

            // Send the publish without waiting for it to complete. This allows us
            // to send multiple message without blocking..
            queue.add(connection.publish(topic, msg, QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE, false));

            // Eventually we start waiting for old publish futures to complete
            // so that we don't create a large in memory buffer of outgoing message.s
            if( queue.size() >= 1000 ) {
                queue.removeFirst().await();
            }

            if( i % 1000 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Sent %d messages.", i));
            }
        }

        queue.add(connection.publish(topic, new AsciiBuffer("SHUTDOWN"), QoS.AT_LEAST_ONCE, false));
        while( !queue.isEmpty() ) {
            queue.removeFirst().await();
        }

        connection.disconnect().await();

        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static String env(String key, String defaultValue) {
        String rc = System.getenv(key);
        if( rc== null )
            return defaultValue;
        return rc;
    }

    private static String arg(String []args, int index, String defaultValue) {
        if( index < args.length )
            return args[index];
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }

}
```

after 15 second its getting timeout error. Here is myactivemq config file

```
<transportConnectors>
    <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
    <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5673?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1888?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61615?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
<transportConnector name="websocket" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

Comment: You should include the error you are getting, and logs from the broker that indicates errors about the dropped connection.

Comment: It is simply getting time out at `connection.connect().await(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`